# Delay Reactive form validation Angular

Tags: angular

I have a form group with a control which has a validator attached to it. The controls update on change. Everything works perfectly, but for better user experience it would be great if validators are executed on change after `X` seconds the user stopped typing.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.signUpForm = new FormGroup(
      {
        userName: new FormControl(null, [
          UsernameValidator.validate,
        ]),
      },
      {
        updateOn: 'change',
      }
    );
}
```

The validator:

```
export class UsernameValidator {
  static validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
    const regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+$/;
    if (control.value) {
      if (!regex.test(control.value)) {
        return { [ErrorTypes.invalidUserName]: true };
      }
      if (control.value.length < 3) {
        return { [ErrorTypes.userNameTooShort]: true };
      }
      if (control.value.length > 30) {
        return { [ErrorTypes.userNameTooLong]: true };
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

I know this is synchronous validation, but is it even possible to achieve the delay?

Comment: Just use an asynchronous validator ?

Comment: But isn't that used with API requests?

Comment: API requests are asynchronous, so yes it CAN be used for that, but it can be used for anything else that is asynchronous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to do it if you make your code `async`

along with [DebounceTime](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/debounceTime)

```
import { FormGroup, FormControl, AbstractControl, ValidationErrors } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { debounceTime, map, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { YourAsyncValidationService } from 'path-to-your-async-validation-service';

export class UsernameValidator {
  static validateAsync(service: YourAsyncValidationService): (control: AbstractControl) => Observable<ValidationErrors | null> {
    return (control: AbstractControl): Observable<ValidationErrors | null> => {
      const regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+$/;

      // If the control is empty, return observable of null (no error)
      if (!control.value) {
        return of(null);
      }

      // Add a delay of 500 milliseconds using debounceTime
      return of(control.value).pipe(
        debounceTime(500),
        switchMap(() => service.validateUsernameAsync(control.value)),
        map(result => {
          if (!regex.test(control.value)) {
            return { [ErrorTypes.invalidUserName]: true };
          }
          if (control.value.length < 3) {
            return { [ErrorTypes.userNameTooShort]: true };
          }
          if (control.value.length > 30) {
            return { [ErrorTypes.userNameTooLong]: true };
          }
          return result ? { [ErrorTypes.asyncValidationFailed]: true } : null;
        })
      );
    };
  }
}

export class YourComponent {
  signUpForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private yourAsyncValidationService: YourAsyncValidationService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.signUpForm = new FormGroup(
      {
        userName: new FormControl(null, {
          asyncValidators: [UsernameValidator.validateAsync(this.yourAsyncValidationService)],
        }),
      },
      {
        updateOn: 'change',
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can delay updating the form validity by changing the updateOn property from change (default) to submit or blur . With template-driven forms, set the property in the template. With reactive forms, set the property in the FormControl instance

From: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation

Comment: I am aware of that, but I would like to validate after a few seconds the change was made, not on blur or submit